# Choosing collisions of hash functions

Tags: c++

According to the condition of the problem, it is necessary to "break" the standard hash "gcc". It is necessary for the program to run for more than 1.5 seconds according to the input data. 15000 string with up to 15 characters 0-9A-Za-z_ is appended to unordered_set.
If I understand correctly, it is necessary to choose such strings, the hash of which will be the same, but it is not clear how

```
auto users_list = getUsers( 15'000u );
auto start_time = std::clock();

for( const auto& user : users_list ) {
    users.insert( user );
}

auto end_time = std::clock();
double spent = static_cast<double>( end_time - start_time ) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

The code of the program to be "broken" (does not change):
https://github.com/NikitaChampion/data-structures/blob/main/contest/hacks/bad-hash-gcc.cpp

Comment: Look at the hash function that GCC uses, reverse engineer it, and calculate multiple strings that hash to the same value? This wont "break" it, but it will cause it to drop from `O(1)` to `O(n)` runtime.

Comment: I do know what a hash function is, I don't know what "breaking" a hash is (I do know collisions). And what does time have to do with breaking hashes in an unordered_map?
You need to provide a compilable example and phrase your question more clearly.

Comment: I do not understand how it is possible to reverse the following sequence of actions:
`for (size_t _Idx = 0; _Idx < _Count; ++_Idx) {
        _Val ^= static_cast<size_t>(_First[_Idx]);
        _Val *= _FNV_prime;
    }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make the program slow, you'd need to find 15000 strings (15 chars or less) with an identical hash.  That will degrade the performance of insertion on `unordered_set` to be equivalent to searching within a linked list for a duplicate and appending the new string at the end.

If your code is running **in the 32-bit space**, a brute force attack on `std::hash<std::string>` is feasible to find 15000 strings with the same hash.

Each string is at most 15 characters long. Each character is one of 63 different values (A-Z, a-z, 0-9, or _).  For a 15 character string, that's `63¹⁵` possible combinations.  But... `std::hash` returns a `size_t` value. And `sizeof(size_t) == 4` on 32-bit machines.  Intuitively thinking... if you hash 4 billion unique strings, you should find at least one pair of strings with identical hashes.  And `63¹⁵` divided by `2³²` is in the neighborhood of 227 quadrillion string with matching hashes for any given 15 character string in your allowed char set.  We only need 15000.  And we don't necessarily need a 15 character string either.

So if we hash all strings from `"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"` to `"ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ"` to find a given hash, we'll eventually find 15000 unique strings that have the same hash.  We can use a shorter string size too to reduce the complexity of hashing.

Basically the algorithm is this:

```
hash<string> hasher;
size_t targetHash = hasher("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"); // find all strings with identical hashes as AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

uint64_t i = 0;
while (true)
{
    string s = generateString(i);
    if (hasher(s) == targetHash))
    {
        cout << s << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Where `generateString` is a function that generates the Nth sequential string in the series. (e.g. `generateString(0) => "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"` and `generateString(1) => "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAB"` )

After I upgraded the code with a few optimizations and to using multiple threads to run in parallel, I was able find identical hashes for the 10 character string `"AAAAAAAAAA"` approximately every 6 seconds or 10 per minute.  Hence, in about 62 hours, we'd have 15000 unique strings computed.

Shove those 15000 strings into a text file and use that as redirected input into your  program.

Doing some quick math, you probably don't need as many as 15000 duplicate strings to break the running time of the program to run longer than 1.5 seconds to that many inserts. You probably only need a fraction of that amount (like 1000 - 5000) to make the program run slow enough.  1000 duplicate strings would generate at least a half-million string comparisons for the insert operations to complete.

On 64-bit architectures, none of this feasible on conventional PC hardware. The chances of collisions are far less since the `size_t` returned by `std::hash` is a 64-bit value. Duplicate hash collisions will be much harder to fine via brute force.  You'd have to reverse engineer the std::hash code.

Comment: What do you mean  reverse engineer the std::hash code? Here is the original code https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/libsupc%2B%2B/hash_bytes.cc
How can I find an algorithm for getting strings with the same hash?